# Data changing and reverting - MS Access frontend for SQL Server backend

Tags: sql-server-2008, vba, ms-access

I have come across a very frustrating and perplexing problem. I have been all over google and have been unable to find anything about it.

System specs:

I am running an Access `.mdb` front end with a SQL Server back end. The tables all have primary keys declared and foreign key relationships. The SQL Server tables are linked to the Access front end via ODBC. A single copy of the Access front end file is located in a shared network location and is accessed by multiple users at any given time. There are about 15 to 20 users that could have an instance of the Access front end file open on their machine. In the front end file there are a lot of queries, forms, and reports. All of the forms and reports have some amount of vba that go along with them. The SQL Server is the Express edition of 2008 R2. All of the user are running Office 2007.

Problem:

I spent a great deal of time updating data in our system about two years ago. Over the last couple of months users have been telling me that data is missing or incorrect when I know that it should be correct after my updates. Because I create backups for the SQL Server database periodically, I was able to look at older version of the database and discovered that the data had in fact been updated as I thought, but now those line of data are missing or incorrect. I am the only person who knows how to update data en masse, and no one would go in and intentionally alter this data. It is widespread enough, that I know it is not the result of an accidental keystroke.

The front end does have some built in features that are used for copying data which I did not create. (In fact I inherited this whole system, and have just made additions and modifications here and there) We are a manufacturing firm that creates custom versions of our standard products, so bills of materials often need to be copied, then modified for the custom version. Yesterday I executed such as copy and ended up with a crazy result. When I copied the bill of materials from the original, it copied an old version of the original product's bill of materials into the custom version's bill. It was insane. I double checked the bom of the original and it was the up to date version, but somehow the old version of the bom ended up copying into the custom product's bom. The only thing I can think of, is that somehow the old data has managed to store itself (from as long as two years ago) in the Access front end, and somehow that data was pulled from by the vba that executes the bom copy function.

Has anyone seen something like this before?

Comment: Sounds to me like the original portion of the VBA has hard coded connections to either a different DSN or completely different database.  Can you see under the hood of the form that returned the crazy data?  If so, what functions or subs does it call?  Track them down, I'd wager you have a direct pointer to a place you don't want it.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion; use a distributed front end method.  It's an industry standard, as it's a known fact that a shared front end can lead to corruption.  Each user should have a copy of the front end on their local HD, and it's easy enough to distribute using a simple BAT file to copy the front end from the network to the HD.

Aside from that, data doesn't magically revert to ancient records.  It's pulling that data from somewhere.  You will need to track the data path and see where it originated from.  Look at the code behind the "Copy" button.  If it's pulling from a linked table, open that table in SQL Server and run the SQL that the Copy function is executing and see if the resulting data is identical to what Access thinks it is.  If not, write a SQL string to filter the data based on what Access returned and see if that record still exists in the table.  If it does, look at each field and see if you can determine why it's pulling the old record instead of the new record.  It's pulling this data from **somewhere**, you have to determine where that "somewhere" is.